# Chrome and Firefox automatically redirect to https on a certain site

Tags: drupal, nginx, haproxy, php

I have a drupal site that runs on nginx and php-fpm with haproxy balancing between multiple servers.

I have two services set up for haproxy: http and https.

if i go to http://subdomain.domain.com, it works fine.
If I go to https://subdomain.domain.com, it also works fine. 
If I then go back to http it now redirects to https.  This happens in firefox and chrome, but not in IE.

Is there some setting somewhere that redirects to https automatically if it knows that it exists?  Perhaps if a secure header is set?

I tried looking at LiveHTTPHeaders, but it only shows the https portion at this point.
I tried looking in Chrome, and it says this:

```
t=1312233405229 [st=  0] +REQUEST_ALIVE                             [dt=192]
t=1312233405229 [st=  0]     URL_REQUEST_START_JOB                  [dt=  0]
                             --> load_flags = 1114241 (ENABLE_LOAD_TIMING | MAIN_FRAME | VALIDATE_CACHE | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                             --> method = "GET"                   
                             --> priority = 0                     
                             --> url = "http://subdomain.domain.com/"   
t=1312233405229 [st=  0]    +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB                  [dt=  0]
                             --> load_flags = 1114241 (ENABLE_LOAD_TIMING | MAIN_FRAME | VALIDATE_CACHE | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                             --> method = "GET"                   
                             --> priority = 0                     
                             --> url = "http://subdomain.domain.com/"   
t=1312233405229 [st=  0]        URL_REQUEST_REDIRECTED              
                                --> location = "https://subdomain.domain.com/"
```

It seems to be doing a redirect, but doesn't say why.

I tried sniffing with Wireshark, but wasn't able to make any sense of it, as I can't get the SSL decryption to work (I have the key).

Comment: I have figured this out.  I had a setting in nginx:
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=7200";

This is a new feature supported by chrome and firefox 4: http://www.chromium.org/sts

Comment: Russ, in case you are still around: I flagged this question to be moved to ServerFault, which is more suited to the topic; and you should make your comment into an answer and accept it!

Comment: Thanks.  I don't' think i was able to before since it was a new acct, but just did.

Comment: you can even accept your own answer. that's totally normal ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figured this out. I had a setting in nginx: add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=7200"; This is a new feature supported by chrome and firefox 4: chromium.org/sts

Comment: To forget HTTPS preference in Firefox clear "Site Preferences" in `History/Clear Recent History`.